# Should I declare GryoMapper as a static field?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, tinkergraph

Looked at the following code, it appears to be thread-safe.

https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/io/gryo/GryoMapper.java

Hoping to use it like

```java
class Foo {
    private static final GryoMapper MAPPER = GryoMapper.build().create();
}
```

instead of

```java
class Foo {
    private final GryoMapper MAPPER = GryoMapper.build().create();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gryo is based on Kryo which is [not thread-safe](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#thread-safety). `GryoMapper` is basically just a builder for `Kryo` instances which means that you should be able to initialize it as a member variable without the `static` declaration. Just be sure that the `Kryo` instances that you spawn from `GryoMapper` are not accessed by multiple threads concurrently as described in the Kryo link provided.